# How to accept JSON with more layers

Tags: entity-framework-core

i got this JSON im trying to accept with a model, but cant seems to figure out how i will accept the double layer JSON.

i just keep getting invalid data so how should my model look ?

JSON

```
{
    "MAC": "04916206f005",
    "DateTime": "2015-01-01 23:59:50",
    "Data": [{
        "Flow": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }]
}
```

Model

```
{
    public class FlowDTO
    {

        [Required]
        public string MacAdr { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public Array[] Data { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FlowMessageFromGateway([FromBody] FlowDTO flowDTO)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return Ok(flowDTO);
        }
    }
```

ERROR i get

```
{
  "Data[0].Flow": [
    "The input was not valid."
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message saying invalid data?  Can you share that error message?

Comment: How are you sending the data to the controller?

Comment: added the error, im using both Postman and swagger to test it out.

Comment: I'm assuming this is c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is how you are sending the data.

Since you are giving it a name "Flow", when deserializing it is expecting Data to have a property called Flow.

You should be able to get this to work by sending the following through Postman:

```
{
    "MAC": "04916206f005",
    "DateTime": "2015-01-01 23:59:50",
    "Data": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

**Edit**

If you are wanting this data to work:

```
{
    "MAC": "04916206f005",
    "DateTime": "2015-01-01 23:59:50",
    "Data": [{
        "Flow": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    }]
}
```

Then you would need to do the following:

1) An object that holds flow

```
public class Data
{
    public List<int> Flow {get; set;}
}
```

2) Update your original model to use the data class

```
public class FlowDTO
{

    [Required]
    public string MacAdr { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public List<Data> Data { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: But is there no way to get nested JSON to work ? with changing the model somehow?

Comment: This works, of course i just had to make array of new models. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)